# forgot to git pull before git push

Tags: git, gitlab, pull-request, git-push, git-pull

I just pushed an update branch with some changes to my GitLab origin repo (which I have forked from another repo on GitLab) and created a merge request (to merge the pushed branch into the upstream repo, where I have forked my origin from). It showed me a merge conflict.

**Problem:**
at the time I have forked off the update branch from the master branch, my master wasn't up to date anymore (there were already some changes on the upstream master)

**Question**:
how can I fix this (I want my commits on top of those commits of the upstream master)? Is it possible to kind of sync my local master with the upstream master and then to incorporate these additional commits in my update branch, push that "updated" update branch to my origin and finally make a new pull request?

**Edit**:

That is the current situation:

[image]

The orange commits (3 and 4) were introduced on upstream after I have forked the repo. So they are not present in my origin and subsequently not in my local repo. So when I push the update branch (commits 5 and 6) to my origin and create a merge request, then I get the error "merge conflict" because these commits are missing in my pushed update branch and subsecently in the merge request (at least that is what I think, why the merge conflict occurs - or could this also have another cause?).

So the solution would be, to somehow get those newly introduced commits (3 and 4) in my origin and from there into my local repo. And then I could create an "updated" update branch containing everything, which I could then push to my origin and create a new merge request. Like so:

[image]

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Use git reflog to find the commit that you want. Revert to that and fix it and then push to your remote master branch. Read up on using git rebase -i to achieve this stuff. Helps a lot.

Comment: `git merge REMOTE_URL master && git push` OR `git pull -r REMOTE_URL master && git push -f`

Comment: There must be a duplicate for this. All you need is to fetch and merge upstream, and push to your pr (as indicated by JBalin)- what is described is a very normal scenario

Comment: @AD7six: yes, I think you are right, I should have researched more thoroughly! I am having a hard time learning git, but it is slowly getting better.

Comment: @everyone: thanks for your time and tips, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to rebase your branch:

```sh
git checkout update

# Fetch commits from upstream
git fetch upstream

# Replay the commits of your update branch over master branch of upstream
git rebase upstream/master
```

Note: this does not update your local `master` but you don't necessarily need to.

Comment: hi, thanks for the tip! The Problem is, I am not allowed to modify the upstream repo (as I am not the owner). So I first have to incorporate the missing commits from the upstream/master in my local update before I push my local update to my origin and create a new merge request from there (at least thats the way I think I have to do it (I am not so super experienced with git))

Comment: oh wait, maybe I got this wrong. I thought your commands were acting on the upstream repo (what is not allowed for me), but they actually act on my local repo, right? If that is correct, then your answer might allready be the solution!

Comment: If you are going to suggest rebasing - the answer must also mention force pushing as otherwise the answer is incomplete

Comment: @Gael: I think this really solves it, thanks! :)

Comment: yes, I will also keep in mind the force push! Thanks! :)